# What Is the Proper Way to Model a Discussion Forum Entity Relationship in OOP?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, data-modeling

I am flexing my OOP muscles and attempting to build an MVC discussion forum web application.  I am working on modeling out my entity relationships between `Forum` objects, `Thread` objects, and `Post` objects. Unfortunately, I've run into a problem which has put my brain into a tailspin. Here's some background:

Definitions:

- `Forum`: a collection of discussion threads (e.g. "Questions and Answers")
- `Thread`: a collection of posts on a particular topic (e.g.
  "What is the meaning of life, the universe, and everything?")
- `Post`: contains the body of a message.
  (e.g. "Duh... it's 42")

Model Design:

Here's my initial draft for modeling my entities. In this model, forums are the root. Forums can contain zero or more threads, and threads can contain 1 or more posts.  For sake of this question, I have kept things as simple as possible.

[image: Forum entity class diagram]

Here are my service classes:
[image: Simplified service classes]

Here's what the database schema looks like:

[image: Database schema]

To create my objects, I am using my interpretation of the [Data Mapper Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) to translate data from the database into entity objects.  The layered architecture looks like this:[image: layered architecture]

Here's where things get a little complex:
My understanding of good OOP design is that entities shouldn't really have to deal with things like "foreign keys", because those are data persistence concerns.  Instead, entities should reference the actual object that the "foreign key" represents.

Therefore I want to make sure my child entities (`Thread` and `Post`) have references to their parents.  This way, when it comes time to persisting them, the data mapper layer can infer the foreign keys by calling a method like this in a `Post` object.  :

```
// get the primary key from the parent object and return it
function getThreadId() {
    return thread.getThreadId();
}
```

One of the problems I've run into is determining **when** I should inject references to parent objects into the entities.

**Approach 1:**
My instincts tell me that the Data Mapper layer should be responsible for this behavior.  Here's a simplified version of what the `build()` method might look like in the `Post` data mapper:

```
// build a post entity
function build( required postId ) {

    // go out to the database and get our dto
    var dto = dao.getById( postId );

    // initialize the entity
    var post = new post( dto.postId, dto.body );

    // inject a reference to the parent object (thread)
    post.setThread( threadDataMapper.getById( dto.threadId ) );

    return post;
}
```

I see a few problems with this approach:

- I've read that in OOP child objects shouldn't really know about their parents and that parents should be responsible for injecting soft references to their children, not the other way around.
- The approach above feels inefficient because each entity has to go out and get a copy of its parent on every new() instance.  If I have a controller that gets a `Thread` entity, the data mapper has to instance both a new `Thread` and a `Forum` (2 trips to the database).  If I then need to get a `Post` from that `Thread` via `getPostById()`, I have to instance the `Post`, and then re-instance the `Thread` and `Forum` again (3 trips to the database). That just smells terrible to me.

**Approach 2:**
Another idea I had was to have my parent entities inject **themselves** into their respective children. So for example, a `Thread` might do this when getting a `Post`:

```
// Get a post by id
function getPostById( id ) {

    // get the post entity from the service layer
    var post = postService.getById( arguments.id );

    // inject a reference of this thread into the post
    post.setThread( this );

    return post;

}
```

This feels a little better! However, the main caveat I've run into is if you want to directly access a `Post` in the application.  Let's say for example you want to have a page for editing a `Post`.  Since the only way to properly construct a post is to go through its `Thread` (and the only way to construct a `Thread` is through its `Forum`) I have to make my controller do a lot more work just to get an instance of a particular `Post`.  This seems like adding a lot of complexity just so I can access a single entity so I can edit it.

**Approach 3:**
Finally, perhaps the simplest approach would be to keep `Forum` entities, `Thread` entities, and `Post` entities completely separate and include their foreign keys as object properties.  However, this approach seems like I'm just using the entities as fancy DTOs as they just hold data and don't contain any business logic:

[image: Simple model]

**Approach 4:** ???

So that's where I am at as of today. Perhaps I'm going about solving this problem all wrong, or maybe there's a pattern that exists already for this type of model that I'm not aware of.   Any help or insight you could offer would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not the guru of OOP design but I guess the answer heavily depends on your app logic.

I think first of all you have to consider your objects as an entity that keeps own internal data in consistency.
E.g., if the Post does not need to know to which thread it belongs in order to update own 'title' and 'body' properties than it should not keep the thread reference at all.
Thread as a posts container should have some sort of reference to the posts.

As the next step let's say we want to improve thread search performance (for the given post find it's parent thread). Or Post internal consistency starts depends on thread (e.g. when thread is blocked Post body could not be updated). 
Post in such case may contain reference to the parent thread (by id or by the instance).
There are [supporters](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=4) and [opponents](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/03/08/link-to-an-aggregate-reference-or-id) of how to store the reference.

Related to creation I guess all entities should have own factories. What instances would be instantiated during creation depends on how you choose to store reference.

Whatever variant you choose it may work for some time until Post starts to depend on too many classes (Thread, Author, List of Best Posts). To keep own consistency post should have the reference to all those classes which expose a lot of external information. That is the time when we have to close Post for modification. All post rules that depends on external objects post should take as a dependency during initialization.